# Distance between arbitrary point and circular arc

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

In $2$D, I have a circular arc with center point $A$ and radius $r$ between the angles $\theta_1, \theta_2$. I want to find the minimal distance between that arc and an arbitrary point $P$.

[image]

Currently what I am doing is:

1. Translate system such that $A$ lies on origin, i.e. $A \rightarrow \bar 0, P \rightarrow P'$
2. Let $\phi$ be the angle of $P'$, if $\theta_1 \le \phi \le \theta_2 $ treat this as distance from circle (Corresponds to $P2$ in the drawing).
3. If $P'$ is not between the opposite rays, it is closest to one of the edges of the arc (Corresponds to $P3$ in the drawing).

What I don't know is what to do in the last case, corresponding to $P1$ in the drawing. I'd expect the answer to be the distance from $P$ to $A$ plus the radius but I cannot prove this result to myself.

Am I right and just missing an obvious proof?

Comment: Your expectation is incorrect: $\overline{P_1A}+r=\overline{P_1A}+\overline{AB}\ge\overline{P_1B}$

Comment: Up to the bisector it is one edge and jumps to the other when you cross the bisector - assuming that you are more than the radius.

Comment: @Moti, and if it is within the radius?

Comment: In the sector - on the radius.

Comment: By within the radius you mean only it if is within the shaded area in the drawing? 
Specifically, P1 will always be closest to one of the edges, regardless of where it falls within the rays?